# Application error: a server-side exception has occurred. Digest: 3433163037

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, next.js, aws-amplify

I have a nextjs application where i have some dynamic routes. eg. users/:id. the problem is when i deploy the application to amplify on aws everything works except dynamic routes. it works on ec2.

we have tried some different methods like rewrites. `source:` /admin-portal/projects/:id    `target:` index.html `type:` 200 (Rewrite). but this also doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What is the error on the server? Are there any logs? If so, please update your question and include them.